# Tikz: Position node along arc

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code snippet is taken directly from the TikZ Manual v.2.10, Section 16.8 Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly.  Instead of distributing the nodes along the arc as shown in the manual, they are heaped atop one-another at the foot of the arc.  Am I missing something?

Ps.  It was not clear to me if the `positioning` extension from the `tikzlibrary` was necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikz {
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\draw (2,0) arc [x radius=1, y radius=2, start angle=0, end angle=180]
\foreach \t in {0,0.125,...,1}
{ node [pos=\t,auto] {\t} };
}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot from Tikz Manual 2.10

[image: nodes along arc]

Comment: Or use `swap` option to show labels above of the curve!

Comment: @skpblack, nice! I would add fill: `[pos=\t,swap,fill=white,inner sep=1pt]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is right!

The problem is that your arc dimensions are too narrow.

Replace `x radius=1, y radius=2` by `x radius=2, y radius=5`, for example.

Also, use `\tiny` for font size. The result will be

[image]

**ps:** the library was not necessary.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikz {
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,5);
\draw (4,0) arc [x radius=2, y radius=5, start angle=0, end angle=180]
\foreach \t in {0,0.125,...,1}
{ node [pos=\t,auto] {\tiny \t} };
}

\end{document}
```

**edit:** following @skpblack suggestion, you can use `swap` option to insert the label on the curve and also `fill` the node background with white colour and change the `inner sep`.

```
node [pos=\t,swap,fill=white,inner sep=1pt] {\tiny \t}
```

[image]

**edit 2:** here is the screenshot from the version **3.0.0** documentation.

[image]

**edit 3:** here is the screenshot from the version **2.10** documentation.

[image]

Comment: But the code I gave was taken directly (unaltered) from the manual and shown to distribute the nodes along the outer edge of the arc.  There should be no need to adjust the font size.  I still don't understand.

Comment: @steven_nevets, do you have the 2.10 version? I have 3.0

Comment: I updated my post with a Tikz Manual 2.10 screenshot.  Notice that the code is a little different than in the 3.0 version with the `node` and the `foreach` reversed.  The 3.0 code did not compile for me until I updated my `pgf`.  Thanks.

Comment: @steven_nevets It is not clear to me if you still have a question or, if you do, what it is. If this answer was satisfactory, please consider accepting it by clicking the greyed-out checkmark to the top left of the answer (by the vote count). If not, could you edit your question to clarify the outstanding issue(s)?

Comment: @sigur I think my issue has been resolved with a slight modification of my code together with an update of `pgf`. Thank you Sigur et al for your suggestions.